# Combine's receive(on:) not dispatching to serial queue, causing data race

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, combine

According to Apple, [`receive(on:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/receive(on:options:)) runs callbacks on a given queue. We use a serial dispatch queue to prevent racing on `localOptionalCancellable` in the code below. But `receiveCancel` is not getting dispatched to that queue. Can someone tell me why?

From the documentation,

> You use the receive(on:options:) operator to receive results and completion on a specific scheduler, such as performing UI work on the main run loop.
>
> ...
>
> Prefer receive(on:options:) over explicit use of dispatch queues when performing work in subscribers. For example, instead of the following pattern:

#### Issue Reproduction:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Example {
    private var localOptionalCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "LocalQueue-\(UUID())")
    
    func misbehavingFunction() {
        self.dispatchQueue.async {
            self.localOptionalCancellable = Just(())
                .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                .receive(on: self.dispatchQueue)
                .handleEvents(
                    receiveCancel: {
                        // Simultaneous accesses to 0x600000364e10, but modification requires exclusive access.
                        // Can be fixed by wrapping in self.dispatchQueue.async {}
                        self.localOptionalCancellable = nil
                    }
                )
                .sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                    receiveValue: { _ in
                        self.localOptionalCancellable = nil
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}

Example().misbehavingFunction()
```

#### Stack Trace:

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x600000364e10, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at  (0x10eeaf12a).
Current access (a modification) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00007fff2ff7be50 swift_beginAccess + 568
3    Combine                            0x00007fff4ba73a40 Publishers.HandleEvents.Inner.cancel() + 71
4    Combine                            0x00007fff4ba74230 protocol witness for Cancellable.cancel() in conformance Publishers.HandleEvents<A>.Inner<A1> + 16
5    Combine                            0x00007fff4b9f10c0 Subscribers.Sink.cancel() + 652
6    Combine                            0x00007fff4b9f1500 protocol witness for Cancellable.cancel() in conformance Subscribers.Sink<A, B> + 16
7    Combine                            0x00007fff4b9dd2d0 AnyCancellable.cancel() + 339
8    Combine                            0x00007fff4b9dd5f0 AnyCancellable.__deallocating_deinit + 9
9    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00007fff2ff7da20 _swift_release_dealloc + 16
13   Combine                            0x00007fff4b9f0da0 Subscribers.Sink.receive(_:) + 54
14   Combine                            0x00007fff4b9f14c0 protocol witness for Subscriber.receive(_:) in conformance Subscribers.Sink<A, B> + 16
15   Combine                            0x00007fff4ba73ed0 Publishers.HandleEvents.Inner.receive(_:) + 129
16   Combine                            0x00007fff4ba74170 protocol witness for Subscriber.receive(_:) in conformance Publishers.HandleEvents<A>.Inner<A1> + 16
17   Combine                            0x00007fff4ba26440 closure #1 in Publishers.ReceiveOn.Inner.receive(_:) + 167
18   libswiftDispatch.dylib             0x000000010e97cad0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
19   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff20105323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
20   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff20106500 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff2010c12e _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 715
22   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff2010cde1 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 403
23   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff20117269 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 782
24   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00007fff6116391b _pthread_wqthread + 290
25   libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00007fff61162b68 start_wqthread + 15
Fatal access conflict detected.
```

Comment: It's a really convoluted way of using Combine that I haven't seen before. Why are you updating `localOptionalCancellable` inside the callback? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The `localOptionalCancellable` is used to keep track of currently executing calls  and restrict them to only 1.

Comment: Saw your answer, and I am not sure how that will help. But still as the code stands currently we are not getting the expected result as documented by Apple.

Comment: Could you please take ten steps backward and explain what you are _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @matt So I use `localOptionalCancellable` to ensure that only one instance of the asynchronous operation runs at a time. At the same time, I need the cancelable and not a boolean as I want to cancel that operation if required. In the reproduction a lot of that detail is hidden.

Comment: Is there something wrong in my understanding of Apple's documentation? If you notice, the race condition can be handled by explicitly wrapping the access in `self.dispatchQueue.async {}`. But this should not be needed when using `receive(on:)`!

Comment: There is a difference between what queue you receive on and what queue you run a piece of code on.

Comment: I see that from the stack trace. But there should not be a difference between what queue you receive on and what queue you run a piece of code on. `receive(on:)` is supposed to guarantee this according to documentation.

Comment: That's not what the documentation says. `receive(on:)` is just about how messages are passed down the pipeline. If you want to do something that affects an externality as a side effect, nothing is guaranteed about that; being on the right queue is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to Apple, `receive(on:options:)` runs callbacks on a given queue.

Not exactly. Here's what the documentation actually says:

> You use the `receive(on:options:)` operator to receive **results** and **completion** on a specific scheduler, such as performing UI work on the main run loop. In contrast with `subscribe(on:options:)`, which affects upstream messages, `receive(on:options:)` changes the execution context of downstream messages.

(Emphasis added.) So `receive(on:)` controls the [`Scheduler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/scheduler) used to call a [`Subscriber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscriber)'s [`receive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscriber/receive(_:)) and [`receive(completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscriber/receive(completion:)) methods. It does **not** control the `Scheduler` used to call the [`Subscription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscription)'s [`request(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscription/request(_:)) or [`cancel()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable/cancel()) methods.

To control the `Scheduler` used to call the `Subscription`'s `cancel()` method, you need to use the [`subscribe(on:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/subscribe(on:options:)) operator downstream of the `handleEvents` operator, like this:

```
            self.localOptionalCancellable = Just(())
                .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                .receive(on: self.dispatchQueue)
                .handleEvents(
                    receiveCancel: {
                        // Simultaneous accesses to 0x600000364e10, but modification requires exclusive access.
                        // Can be fixed by wrapping in self.dispatchQueue.async {}
                        self.localOptionalCancellable = nil
                    }
                )
                .subscribe(on: self.dispatchQueue)
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                .sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                    receiveValue: { _ in
                        self.localOptionalCancellable = nil
                    }
                )
```

Comment: Thanks! But how did you figure out the order of these things? I tried placing `subscribe` before  `handleEvents` and that still leads to crash due to the same reason.

Comment: You can think of outputs and completion as traveling down from the initial publisher (`Just`) to the subscriber (`sink`), and cancellation as traveling up from the subscriber to the publisher. If the cancellation doesn't pass through the `subscribe(on:)` before reaching `handleEvents`, then the `subscribe(on:)` won't have any effect on how `handleEvents` is called.

Comment: I tried using this in my actual code. But interestingly, if I set the `AnyCancellable` returned by `sink` to `nil` from another function. Or use a `Subscribers.Sink<>` object passed to `subscribe()` and call its `cancel()` from another function, the `receiveCancel` callback does not run. It runs if I don't have  `subscribe(on:options:)` in the chain.

Comment: The completion may have already propagated down the chain past the `handleEvents`, causing the cancellable to have no effect.

Comment: How can I avoid that from happening?

Comment: I don't think you can, in general. You should probably also use `handleEvent`'s `receiveCompletion` argument if you want to reliably detect when the subscription ends.

Comment: Or use `sink`'s `receiveCompletion` argument.

Comment: I am using `sink`'s `receiveCompletion`. But that does not fire...